# How to use limit and skip in spring data mongodb repository?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want query sublist in mongo collections using Spring Data MongoDB.
My Code is like

```java
public interface SomeRepo extends MongoRepository<SomeDoc, String> {
    @Query("{'field0': ?0, 'field1': ?1}, {'limit':?2, 'skip':?3}")
    List<SomeDoc> findAllByField0AndFiled1(
        Long field0,
        Long field1,
        Long limit,
        Long skip
    );
}
```

but `limit` & `skip` are not in Query Object

Log is
`Created query Document{{field0=123, field1=456}} for Document{{}} fields.`

how to pass them into query object?

Comment: Instead of `@Query` use `@Aggregate`.

Comment: You can also use Pageable interface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @prasad_ for the answer.
Using @Aggregation can solve my question.

```
@Aggregation("{'field0': ?0, 'field1': ?1}, {limit': ?2, 'skip': ?3}")
    List<SomeDoc> findAllByField0AndFiled1(
        Long field0,
        Long field1,
        Long limit,
        Long skip
    );
```