# Query in MongoRepository with Limit

Tags: mongodb

```
@Query(value = "{$and:[{'contentRoot.basicData.code':{$ne:null}}" +
        ",{'contentRoot.basicData.tourOperatorCode':{$ne:null}}]}"
        ,fields = "{$and: [{productCode: 1, tourOperatorCode: 1}]}")
```

I try to get 3 Documents from Mongodb. I don´t know where can i use {$limit: 3}, or alternative command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it at the end of the query.

```
@Query("{'source':?0,'target':?1}", sort = "{'date': -1}", limit = 1)
```

Or you can use the  **@Aggregation** annotation

read this for more details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71292598/8470055

Comment: It doesn´t work with    @Query(value=....)

Comment: The code snippet here seems to be from a 10 year old github issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/1492#issuecomment-752649068). Was that feature implemented with that syntax, does it still work that way, and how can the OP use that for their particular question?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide `Pageable` as query method parameter

```
@Query(value = "{$and:[{'contentRoot.basicData.code':{$ne:null}}" +
        ",{'contentRoot.basicData.tourOperatorCode':{$ne:null}}]}"
        ,fields = "{$and: [{productCode: 1, tourOperatorCode: 1}]}")
List<Object> findTop3Objects(Pageable pageable);
```

And init `Pageable` this way:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.ofSize(3);
```